# C Structure Declaration Issue

Tags: c

I am writing the following program for my Programming Fundamentals Class (C Programming). My IDE is giving me a compile error for the declaration of 'student' as referenced in the lines where user input is read. It is also giving me an error on ISO C standards for nested functions in the letter_grade function.  Any help would greatly be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 20

char letter_grade(float a, float b, float c);

int main(void)
{
char temp_name[MAX];
int count=0, last, temp;

struct student {
   char f_name[MAX];
   char l_name[MAX];
   float test1;
   float test2;
   float test3;
  };

printf("Please enter the student's last name (Enter ZZZ to exit): ");
   gets(temp_name);

while (strncmp(temp_name, "ZZZ\0", 4))
{
   strncpy(student[count].l_name, temp_name, MAX+1);
   printf("Please enter the students first name: ");
     scanf("%s", &student[count].f_name);
   getchar();
   printf("Enter the first test score: ");
     scanf("%f", &student[count].test1);
   printf("Enter the second test score: ");
     scanf("%f", &student[count].test2);
   printf("Enter the third test score: ");
     scanf("%f", &student[count].test3);
   printf("\nPlease enter the student's last name (Enter ZZZ to exit): ");
     gets(temp_name);
   count++;
}

last = count;

temp = last + 1;

printf("\t\t\tStudent Grade Report");

for (last;last>=0;last--){
    printf("%s, ", student[last].l_name);
    printf("%s ", student[last].f_name);
    printf("\t\t Grade: %c\n\n ", letter_grade(student[last].test1, student[last].test2, student[last].test2));




//    printf("Test Grade: %c\n", letter_grade(85,88,82));


return 0;
}

char letter_grade(float *a, float *b, float *c)
{
float sum = *a+*b+*c;

if (sum >= 270.0f)
   return 'A';
if (sum>= 240.0f && sum <270.0f)
   return 'B';
if (sum>= 210.0f && sum <240.0f)
   return 'C';
if (sum>= 180.0f && sum <210.0f)
   return 'D';
if (sum < 180.0f)
   return 'F';
}
```

Comment: `l_name` is `char l_name[MAX];` but you tell `strncpy` to copy up to `MAX+1`. Just use `strcpy`.

Comment: strongly suggest: consistently indent the code.  indent after EVERY opening brace '{'.  unindent BEFORE every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces as that is wide enough to be visible even with a variable width font.

Comment: a char string, like "ZZZ\0" will automatically get a '\0' terminator byte, making the array be 5 characters long.  HOWEVER, the function `strncmp()` will stop comparing when it encounters a '\0' in either string.

Comment: it is a poor programming practice to have multiple exit points from a function.  The function `letter_grade()`  would be better written asL 1) having a local variable: `char grade;` then each 'if' other than the first be a `else if`.  Each 'if' sets the variable 'grade'.  the final line at the end of the function: `return grade;`

Comment: strongly suggest moving the `definition` of `struct student` to before the `main()` function.

Comment: the function: `gets()` has been deprecated for many years and completely removed in the latest C standard.  In any case, your compiler should have warned you about using the function `gets()`  Strongly suggest using the function: `fgets()`

Comment: the posted code fails to compile.  Amongst other reasons, the function: `letter_grade()` has a execution path with no `return` statement.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of function, 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the `%s` format specifier, always include a MAX LENGTH modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer, so the user does not overrun the input buffer.  Such overrun is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Answer (score 2):

You nowhere declared an array or a pointer with name `student`. The name was  not declared. Thus the code where you are refering the name like this statement

```
strncpy(student[count].l_name, temp_name, MAX+1);
        ^^^^^^^
```

is invalid.

What is "student"? Where is it declared?

You only declared type `struct student` but it is not the same as an object with name `student`.

Also in this loop

```
for (last;last>=0;last--){
    printf("%s, ", student[last].l_name);
    printf("%s ", student[last].f_name);
    printf("\t\t Grade: %c\n\n ", letter_grade(student[last].test1, student[last].test2, student[last].test2));
```

there is absent the closing brace.

Answer (score 1):

Applying all the comments and correcting other problems in the posted code *there were many* results in:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NAME_LEN (20)
#define MAX_STUDENTS (100)

// define the student struc
struct student 
{
   char f_name[ MAX_NAME_LEN ];
   char l_name[ MAX_NAME_LEN ];
   float test1;
   float test2;
   float test3;
};

char letter_grade(float a, float b, float c);

int main(void)
{
    // define an array of 100 instances of the student struct
    struct student students[ MAX_STUDENTS ];

    printf("Please enter the student's last name (Enter ZZZ to exit): ");

    int count=0;      
    while( count < MAX_STUDENTS && scanf( " %19s", students[count].l_name)  && strcmp( students[count].l_name, "ZZZ" ) )
    {
         printf("Please enter the students first name: ");
         scanf(" %19s", students[count].f_name);

         printf("Enter the first test score: ");
         scanf("%f", &students[count].test1);

         printf("Enter the second test score: ");
         scanf("%f", &students[count].test2);

         printf("Enter the third test score: ");
         scanf("%f", &students[count].test3);

        count++;

        printf("\nPlease enter the student's last name (Enter ZZZ to exit): ");
    } // end while

    printf("\t\t\tStudent Grade Report");

    for ( ; count>=0; count--)
    {
        printf("%s, ", students[count].l_name);
        printf("%s ", students[count].f_name);
        printf("\t\t Grade: %c\n\n ", 
                letter_grade(   students[count].test1, 
                                students[count].test2, 
                                students[count].test2));
    }  // end for
} // end function: main


char letter_grade(float a, float b, float c)
{
    float sum = a+b+c;
    char grade;

    if( sum >= 270.f)      grade = 'A';
    else if (sum>= 240.0f) grade = 'B';
    else if (sum>= 210.0f) grade = 'C';
    else if (sum>= 180.0f) grade = 'D';
    else                   grade = 'F';

    return grade;
} // end function: letter_grade
```

You can compare the posted code to the above answer to spot where there were problems in the posted code.

Do not `#include` header files those contents are not used.

A passed value to a function does not become a pointer in the parameter list of the called function.

In any `if then else` sequence, there is no need to re-test for previously eliminated values

The posted code nested one function inside another,  That is not valid C code, although can be allowed with the `gcc` compiler extension.

There is no need for a `return` statement from `main()` if the returned value is 0.

On any non void function, ALL paths through the code must lead to a `return value;` statement.

The posted code failed to declare any instance of the `struct student` structure.  And certainly did not declare an array of those struct instances, as is needed when multiple students being processed.

The posted code (and this answer) will fail if any first or last name is greater than or equal to 20 characters.

This answer does not check for failures of the call to `scanf()`  but for reliability, such checking for each must be performed.  Similar to:

```
if( 1 != scanf( " %19s", students[count].l_name) )
{
    perror( "scanf failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); // `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` found in stdlib.h
}

// implied else, scanf successful
```

The `while()` statement in the `main()` function is very 'busy' for clarity, the call to `strcmp()` could be extracted and placed in a following statement similar to:

```
while(...)
{
    if( !strcmp( students[count].l_name, "ZZZ" ) {
    {
         break;
    }
    ...
```

In general, never trust the input from a user.  That is why the returned value (not the parameter value) from each call to `scanf()` needs to be checked.

As a simplification, rather than hardcoding the MAX LENGTH modifier in the calls to `scanf()` with a `%s` format specifier, can use the following changes:

```
#define MAX_NAME_LEN (19)
...
struct student 
{
   char f_name[ MAX_NAME_LEN+1 ];
   char l_name[ MAX_NAME_LEN+1 ];
   float test1;
   float test2;
   float test3;
};
....
    && scanf(" %" MAX_NAME_LEN "s", students[count].l_name) &&
....
    scanf(" %" NAX_NAME_LEN "s", students[count].f_name);
```

Comment: Note: this parameter to `printf()` `letter_grade(   students[count].test1, 
                                students[count].test2, 
                                students[count].test2));` probably should have the second `students[count].test2` replaced with: `students[count].test3`